# bootstrap, how can I make a size4 column skip a size12 column if there is room in the row above

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to do is to make a 3x3grid with bootstrap 'col-md-4' elements. Every grid element has a button. When a button is clicked in a grid element, that grid element expands to size 12

Is there a easy way to make something like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHgwb.png). I mean force the next 'col-md-4' item to
moved to an empty space above col-md-12 in top row (if there is space).

[please check fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roxg9p1s/2/)

html:

```
            <div id="functions" class="row">
                <div id="funkcja1" class="function_item funkcja col-md-4">
                    <div class="function_inside">       
                            <p>f1</p>
                            <button class="sidebar-hide-btn" type="button">more</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="funkcja2" class="function_item funkcja col-md-4">
                    <div class="function_inside">       
                            <p>f2</p>
                            <button class="sidebar-hide-btn" type="button">more</button>
                    </div>  </div>
                    
                <div id="funkcja3" class="function_item funkcja col-md-4">
            <div class="function_inside">       
                            <p>f3</p>
                            <button class="sidebar-hide-btn" type="button">more</button>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                
                <div id="funkcja4" class="function_item funkcja col-md-4">
                    <div class="function_inside">       
                            <p>f4</p>
                            <button class="sidebar-hide-btn" type="button">more</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="funkcja5" class="function_item funkcja col-md-4">
                    <div class="function_inside">       
                            <p>f5</p>
                            <button class="sidebar-hide-btn" type="button">more</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="funkcja6" class="function_item funkcja col-md-4">
                    <div class="function_inside">       
                            <p>f6</p>
                            <button class="sidebar-hide-btn" type="button">more</button>
                    </div>  </div>
                <div id="funkcja7" class="function_item funkcja col-md-4">
                    <div class="function_inside">       
                            <p>f7</p>
                            <button class="sidebar-hide-btn" type="button">more</button>
                    </div>  </div>
                <div id="funkcja8" class="function_item funkcja col-md-4">
                    <div class="function_inside">       
                            <p>f8</p>
                            <button class="sidebar-hide-btn" type="button">more</button>
                    </div>  </div>
                <div id="funkcja9" class="function_item  col-md-4">
                    <div class="function_inside">       
                            <p>f9</p>
                            <button class="sidebar-hide-btn" type="button">more</button>
                    </div>  </div>
            </div>
```

js:

```
                jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
            $(".btn").click(function() {

            $('#functions').children().not('select').removeClass('col-md-12');
            $('#functions').children().not('select').addClass('col-md-4');

            $(this).closest('.function_item').removeClass('col-md-4').addClass('col-md-12');
             
            });});
```

Comment: No, probably no totally trivial way. BS4 uses flexbox, so you could set the `order` property of those column elements dynamically, to move them to a different position. (Alternatively, you could also move the elements in the DOM - but that is likely to cause additional problems with bound event handlers.) But you will have to write some additional logic that checks based on the original position of the elements, which one(s) will have to be moved, each time you switch one of them from col-4 to col-12.

Answer (score 0):

1. Give an unique id attribute to each red box (from 0 to 8).
2. Attach class name modifications to click event (as you have already done in sample code)
3. Check the order of clicked box with a remainder function (remainder of 3)
4. Move the following boxes (just after clicked box) into empty spaces regarding to remainder function output.

These jQuery functions can be useful:

```
.insertBefore()

.detach()

.prepend()
```